# Parse data from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have looked online and SO but have not found anything similar to help. I have data in a cell and want to parse or extract the data like shown in this image

[image]

I am thinking VBA is the way to go vs formula.  I am ok with formulas and a newby with VBA.

Comment: Are the Date/Time and "Action for" in a single cell with a line break or in two cells?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald It's even worse. Obviously **everything** is in one cell as you can see from the screenshot.  Even there is more than one "date/time" and "Action for" in one cell. Everything is in cell `A1` and blocks are only separated by a free line within that cell. First thing should be to separate the blocks into own cells and then separate the dates from the actions. This should be only possible with VBA, I don't see any possibility for formulas.

Comment: I think the better question should be, where does the data come from? What is the source format. I think the first fault here is having everything in A1 and it would be much easier if there was a possibility to do some pre-processing before it is imported into Excel.

Comment: @Peh, I agree that getting the source data changed to a usable format is preferable.  Failing that, the OP is going to have to use the VBA Split function to stuff all the elements into a variant array then do some processing on that.

Comment: Mark - It is not idea to say the least.  Peh - It is coming from a tool that i have no control over.  We are trying to modify the way the data comes out and will eventually... Until then, this is all i have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I typed your first example in to a cell and used the "text to column" function and it splits it out if you set the delimiters where you want them. However, if your text then changes you will need to re-do the delimiters.

Comment: Well, it does depend on what you want exactly, one solution could be to replace with nothing all the characters that you don't want before you parse the data. The text you show in A1 came out fine for me, but removing the "-"  before parsing would reduce 1 column in the result.